# Materialize Dropdown hide behind other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I added some dropdown menus from [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/select.html) and I'm having issues with them being behind other elements (pic attached). I have tried changing the z-index of the options (`z-index: 100;`) and the z-index of the other divs (`z-index: -1;`).

HTML:

```
                      <div class="column source">
                          <label for="source1">Source of Income</label>
                          <select class="validate dark" id="source1" value="<?= income1Data[1] ?>" onchange="getHeader1();" required>
                            <option disabled><?= income1Data[1] ?></option>
                            <option>Employment</option>
                            <option>Unemployment</option>
                            <option>Social Security</option>
                            <option>Retirement</option>
                            <option>Side Job</option>
                            <option>Benefits</option>
                            <option>Bonus</option>
                            <option>Other</option>
                          </select>
                      </div>

           <div class="table-body x18" id="bill-table">
             <hr />
             <div class="table-row x20">
               <h3 class="title">Bills and Debt</h3>
             </div>
           </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elements);
};
```

CSS:

```
#bill-table {
  z-index:-1;
}

ul.dropdown-content.select-dropdown li span {
    z-index:100; //I used "color: red" to test and the color works, but z-index doesn't bring to front
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` property won't do any effect if the elements aren't positioned, try to add a `position` property foreach bloc based on your use case

Comment: between you and @Luke Bennett, i got it! Luke explained about the z-index. The solution was simple, I just had to add ```position: relative;``` to the ```#bill-table``` div.

Answer (score 1):

I think that perhaps the issue you are experiencing here is due to the fact that z-index only works on positioned elements, e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

I made a quick fiddle here to explain it: https://jsfiddle.net/LukeUK/ptym15qx/10/
Hope this helps! :)

CSS

```
.pink-square {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: pink;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.blue-square {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background: blue;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="pink-square"></div>
<div class="blue-square"></div>
```

Comment: That clearly explains the z-index! Thank you for letting me know, I didn't realize that. Is there another route to take to bring the menu to the front?

Comment: I tried adding the position to the dropdown and it didn't work. It worked when I added the position to the other divs instead (that were previously causing the dropdown to hide).

Comment: No worries! :) Ahh interesting, so the positioning didn't work on the `<select>` element? But it did on the `<div>` elements? We're you able to achieve what you needed still? Or do you need further help?